# Sympy plotting graph upside down?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

Am using sympy plotting backend. The graphs of functions are being inverted and I don't know why. For example y=x^2 is [upsidedown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAShB.png) with the negative y axis on top.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import *
import spb
import sympy as sympy


def queryMatplotlibEq(qVal,labels, color, xBounds, yBounds):
    toShow = None
    if (labels == "true"):
        toShow = "center"

    qVal = qVal.replace('^', "**")

    x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)

    lhs, rhs = qVal.split('=')

    lhs = eval(lhs)
    rhs = eval(rhs)

    expr = lhs - rhs
    sols = solve(expr, y)

    plot = spb.plot(*sols, (x, xBounds[0], xBounds[1]), {"color": f"{color}", "markersize": "1"}, legend=False, aspect="equal", ylim=(
        yBounds[0], yBounds[1]), xlim=(xBounds[0], xBounds[1]), grid=toShow, show=False, adaptive=False, n=70000, is_point=True, axis_center=(0, 0))

    plot.show()
question = "y=x**2"
x, y = symbols("x y")
# [[-2.0, 2.3], [26.75, 31.0]]


xExtents = [-13, 13]
yExtents = [10, -30]

queryMatplotlibEq(question,"true","blue" ,xExtents,yExtents)
```

Comment: By the way, you should use boolean variables rather than strings, i.e. `True` over `"true"`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I agree it would be more efficient to use booleans. For my use case however I have the booleans coming through JSON from a frontend application as strings, so I worked with what I had setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yExtents` gets passed to matplotlib's `set_ylim`. If the first value is negative and the second is positive, then you'll get what you expect. Instead, you specified a positive first value and a negative second value, hence you get a reverse y-axis.